# How do I sequentially loop an observable in RxSwift?

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I am trying to create a stream that polls a network service. At the moment it queries the service then completes after a short delay. I'd like the onward stream to restart rather than completing thereby polling the service forever.

You could do something like ...

```
myPollingStream.repeat()
```

But `repeat` in RxSwift is actually `repeatElement` and so actually generates a stream of observables. You could possibly `concatMap` these into a flattened serial sequence but RxSwift does not have the `concatMap` operator.

So how do I loop an observable in RxSwift?

I'd like the requests to be sequential, not concurrent so `flatMap` is not an option since it merges streams leading to overlapping requests. I'm looking for something similar to how `retry()` works but restarting `onComplete` not `onError`

Answer (score 8):

```
Observable.repeatElement(myPollingStream, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance).concat()
```

- `repeatElement(_:scheduler:)` will create an infinite stream of polling queries.
- `contat()` will then make sure each polling query is completed before subscribing to the next.

### Attention

While the above works in theory, without a backpressure implemetation, `repeatElements(_:scheduler:)` will emit events until you eventually run out of memory. This makes this solution not viable as of RxSwift 3.0. More details can be found in [this issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/1093#issuecomment-279142758) on RxSwift repository.

Comment: it save my day @tomahh

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1: Recursive function**

Your `myPollingStream`:

```
func myPollingStream() -> Observable<Result> { 
    return Observable<String>.create { observer in
        // your network code here


        return Disposables.create()
    }
}
```

Then you create a a recursive function:

```
func callMyPollingStream() {
    myPollingStream()
        .subscribe(onNext: { result in
            callMyPollingStream() // when onNext or onCompleted, call it again 
        })
        .addDisposableTo(db)
}
```

**Option 2: Use interval**

```
let _ = Observable<Int>
            .interval(5, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
            .subscribe(onNext: { _ in
                let _ = myPollingStream().subscribe()
            })
            .addDisposableTo(db)
```

With this option, myPollingStream() function will be called every 5 seconds.

Comment: Hmm I was reluctant to use recursion because this is an infinite loop and if it is not tail call optimised then we could end up with a stack overflow

Comment: @Brendan I have added another option using intervals

Comment: Cheers, the interval option overlaps the calls though, I'm looking for a way which is sequential I.e. Will only fire the next call when the first has completed

Comment: Did you find a solution in the end? @Brendan